How to solve a SSL certificate verify problem?
I'm working on a website and I want to add an email sending option.
I wrote the following code.
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = ’mail.@.com’;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = *****;
$mail->Password = ****;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->setFrom(’****.com’,’John’);

$mail->addAddress(’*****.com’,’Doe’);

$mail->Subject = 'email test;
$mail->isHTML(TRUE);
$mail->Body = 'html>';


if(!$mail->send()){
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}

But I got the following error.

Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [PHPMailer-master\src\SMTP.php line 490]
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

I changed the port several times. And I also changed the value of SMTPSecure several times.
UPDATE :
The total error message:
2024-07-02 10:51:46 Connection: opening to mail.@.com:25, timeout=300, options=array()
2024-07-02 10:51:46 Connection: opened
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SMTP INBOUND: "220 mail.@.com NO UCE ESMTP Postfix (2.10.1)"
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mail.@.com NO UCE ESMTP Postfix (2.10.1)
2024-07-02 10:51:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250-mail.@.com"
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250-PIPELINING"
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250-SIZE 20857600"
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250-VRFY"
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ETRN"
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250-STARTTLS"
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250-8BITMIME"
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SMTP INBOUND: "250 DSN"
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mail.@.com250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 20857600250-VRFY250-ETRN250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250 DSN
2024-07-02 10:51:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SMTP INBOUND: "220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS"
2024-07-02 10:51:46 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2024-07-02 10:51:46 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [\PHPMailer-master\src\SMTP.php line 490]
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
2024-07-02 10:51:46 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT


"I changed the port several times. And I also changed the value of SMTPSecure several times." - why the guessing game? You should know the correct values for both beforehand; the provider of the SMTP server should give you that info.

Port 25 is typically not encrypted, but system administrators can set their servers as they see fit. Don't guess, check your provider settings.

Port 25 can't offer implicit encryption (ssl mode in PHPMailer), but tls mode is fine. Setting $mail->SMTPDebug = 4 should give you more info about why the certificate check is failing; it's most likely a name mismatch.

"Postfix (2.10.1)" - if you have any chance to contact the admin of that mailserver, please warn them that this version of Postfix is horribly outdated. Released in 2013, there are tons of known bugs and security holes

Is it an internal mailserver? Who signed the SSL certificate? Do you really need to use SSL?

You may not be able to solve this issue without examining the certificate. I would assume the error message is correct and there is something wrong with the server certificate. It would be nice if that message had a little bit more detail. Here is a related question which, although old, has several tools that you can use to perhaps pinpoint what's wrong with the certificate. I may have to vote to close the question because I don't think it contains enough detail to do much more than guess at the problem.
